# How can I export a txt table to latex?

Tags: tables, code, python, files

[image: My table from a python code]

I have txt file with table format, I did it in python but now I have to export this table to Latex but I don't know how. I'm not good at all in latex so I'll appreciate if you help me.

Thank you!

Comment: You may check out [`pgfplotstable`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) which can take a txt file input.

Comment: Ohh excelent, thankss:)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, here are some of them:

**1. according to [@Teddy van Jerry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/234654/teddy-van-jerry) using `pgfplotstable`**

*Your `.txt` file:*

```
    x y
    1 2
    2 4
    3 6
    4 8
```

*Your `.tex` file*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=space,
    columns={x,y},
    columns/x/.style={column name=$x$, column type={|c}},
    columns/y/.style={column name=$y$, column type={c|}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline, after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
]{data.txt}
\end{document}
```

*Result*

[image]

**2. Using `\usepackage{csvsimple}`**

Your `.txt` file:

```
Name, Age, Gender
John, 30, Male
Sarah, 25, Female
Bob, 45, Male
```

Your `.tex` file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\csvreader[    tabular=|c|c|c|,    table head=\hline Name & Age & Gender \\\hline,    late after line=\\\hline,    ]{data.txt}{Name=\name,Age=\age,Gender=\gender}{\name & \age & \gender}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

*Result*

[image]